# Pass Variable to "Relation" parameter in Excel Solver VBA

Tags: excel, vba, solver

I am attempting to change the relation in VBA solver based on a formula found in cell (I28). Sometimes I want the constraint relationship to be "=" and sometimes ">=". The output from the formula in I28 is either (2) or (3) My idea is summarized below in line 7:

```
Dim relI As Range
Set relI = Value.Range("i28")
With relI
    SolverReset
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$m$3", Relation:=1, FormulaText:="$e$25"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$g$21", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="$C$19"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$I$21", Relation:=relI, FormulaText:="$I$22"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$C$9:$C$17", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="$D$9:$D$17"
    SolverOk SetCell:="$h$21", MaxMinVal:=1, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$g$8:$g$17", _
        Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
End With
```

How do I / Can I pass that variable to the solver in this way?

Comment: Does that line throw an error?

Comment: @BigBen - i get " Compile Error: ByRef argument type mismatch"

Comment: Try `RelI.Value`.

Comment: @BigBen that threw an error back up where I declared `Rel_I`, but you comment gave me the idea to try `Relation:=Range("I28").Value` within the solver and that worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@BigBen helped solve this problem. This solution will call the variable from within a cell. For me, this is a better solution than declaring a variable in VBA.

```
SolverReset
SolverAdd CellRef:="$M$3", Relation:=1, FormulaText:="$E$25"
SolverAdd CellRef:="$G$21", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="$C$19"
SolverAdd CellRef:="$I$21", Relation:=Range("I28").Value, FormulaText:="$I$22"
SolverAdd CellRef:="$C$9:$C$17", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="$D$9:$D$17"
SolverOk SetCell:="$H$21", MaxMinVal:=1, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$G$8:$G$17", _
    Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
```